# mod_rewrite loaded but phpbb url rewrite option not working

Tags: 16.04, apache2, php, mod-rewrite, phpbb

mod_rewrite PHP module loaded but phpbb URL rewrite option not working

```
Software Versions:
- Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
- Apache 2.4.18
- PHP 7.0
- Loaded Modules: Virtual Server    Yes
Server Root /etc/apache2
Loaded Modules

    core mod_so 
    mod_watchdog 
    http_core 
    mod_log_config 
    mod_logio 
    mod_version 
    mod_unixd 
    mod_access_compat 
    mod_alias 
    mod_auth_basic 
    mod_authn_core 
    mod_authn_file 
    mod_authz_core 
    mod_authz_host 
    mod_authz_user 
    mod_autoindex 
    mod_deflate 
    mod_dir 
    mod_env 
    mod_filter 
    mod_mime 
    prefork 
    mod_negotiation 
    mod_php7 
    mod_rewrite 
    mod_security2 
    mod_setenvif 
    mod_socache_shmcb 
    mod_ssl 
    mod_status 
    mod_unique_id 
    mod_xml2enc
```

000-default.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName www.example.net
        ServerAlias example.net
        Redirect /* https://www.example.net/$1

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/certificate.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/private.key

        ServerAdmin administrator@example.net

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined         
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

<IfModule security2_module.c>
    SecRuleEngine on
    ServerTokens Full
    SecServerSignature "MyCustomServer/1.12"
</IfModule>
```

If any more information is needed, ask for it.
p.s. I am new to ubuntu

Comment: Mod Rewrite should be enabled for this directory. [Edit] the question and add the content of your virtual host configuration file. The default one is `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`.

Comment: added the config to my post

Answer (score 0):

Modify your configuration file and add the following lines right after the `DocumentRoot` directive. Then restart Apache.

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options None FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

The directive `AllowOverride All` should allow all overrides by the .htaccess file for this directory. By default it is: `AllowOverride None`.

Further reading:

- [AllowOverride Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride)
- [Apache HTTP Server Tutorial: .htaccess files](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html)

Comment: Still not working(I already restarted apache2)

Comment: @TheBlueKingLP: Is there exist `.htaccess` file, writable for Apache's user `www-data`? If not, try to create one: `sudo touch /var/www/html/.htaccess && sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/html/.htaccess`.

Comment: still not working...

Comment: @TheBlueKingLP: What actually should be happen? I've read a bit about phpbb and I think you should add your rules [manually](http://mrbool.com/how-to-go-for-apache-mod-rewrite-and-seo-for-phpbb-forums/25892). Isn't it?